# Java Listener for Mysql Table change

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a MySQL database. When I adding data to a specific table,
I want to execute a java service using these data(data like email, time etc). This service will send Emails and SMSs to some users.

Is there a way to implement this kind of service using mySQL and java??
I have Email and SMSs things. I just want to know about the MySQL support for this kind of Listener.

If not please give me alternative solution.

Comment: I think that this question has already been answered [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/execution-of-a-java-program-by-a-trigger).